# Spreadsheet calculation - determine number of days in a month

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2007

```
Expenses                                            Shift  Jan-12 Feb-12 Mar-12 Apr-12  
                                                      1                 
Jan-12       Feb-12       Mar-12       Apr-12         2                             
$11,699.09   $11,129.28   $11,306.50   $11,125.85     3
                                                      4
                                                      5         
                                                      6                 
                                                      7
```

Each shift consists of 2 hours, and since there are 7 shifts, there's in all 14 hours.

For Jan:31 days, Feb:29 days, Mar:31 days, Apr:30 days. With that, I need to calculate expenses per month.

For eg, Jan: 11,666.09/31 days/14hours*2hours.

And for feb: 11,129.28/29/14*2.

So is there any formula that I can use in Excel without having to type in the formula one by one just because the days differ for each month?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that your month headings are proper Excel dates (not just textual representations of dates) and then you can use a formula to calculate the number of days in a particular month in, say, cell A1:

```
=EOMONTH(A1,0)-EOMONTH(A1,-1)
```